# Formatting the filter function inside array with if else condition

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, object, ecmascript-6

Into the below code there are the `usersData` object which contains the `usersList` array.

```js
const usersData = {
  usersList: [
    {
      user: "user1",
      langSpeak: ["IND","SPN"],
    },
    {
      
      user: "user2",
      langSpeak: ["IND"],
    },
    {
     
      user: "user1",
      langSpeak: ["IND", "SPN", "JPN"],
    },
    {
     
      user: "user3",
      langSpeak: ["IND", "SPN"],
    },
    {
      user: "user3"
    }
  ]
};

let usersKey = ["user","langSpeak"];
let usersValue = ["user1","IND","SPN"];
 
 let userColl = usersData.usersList.filter(userObj => {
  
  return usersKey.forEach( usersKey => {
    if(Array.isArray(userObj[usersKey])){
      return userObj[usersKey] && usersValue.forEach(x => {
        console.log("x===" + usersKey)
        return userObj[usersKey].includes(x)
      });
    }
     if(!Array.isArray(userObj[usersKey])){
      console.log(usersKey)
      return usersValue.includes(userObj[usersKey]);
    } 
  
      
  });
});

console.log(userColl);
```

There are the `usersKey` and `usersValue`.

Code is already there for the filter key and values.

I checked into the filter function if the value contains the array or not depending on that return the filter data.

And the final output is stored into the `userColl` variable.

Currently I am getting `null` in output but I am expecting  **first** and **third** `userList` object; also the condition is that I do not want to change the `usersKey` and `usersValue`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide the expected JSON or output also

Comment: Expected Output :
usersList: [
    {
      user: "user1",
      langSpeak: ["IND","SPN"],
    },
    {
     
      user: "user1",
      langSpeak: ["IND", "SPN", "JPN"],
    }]

Comment: What is the use of `usersKey` and `userValue`?

Comment: And, the key 'code'  is not present in anywhere in the original JSON?

Comment: Shouldn't `usersKey` be `["user", "langSpeak"]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `Array.forEach` you should use `Array.every` to check the presence of the required data in the given array.

Then using the boolean returned from the `every` call can be used as the filter criteria to filter the data.

The `Array.forEach` doesn't return anything but `Array.filter` expects a boolean predicate to test but in your code `forEach` will return `undefined`.

Also the second key should be `langSpeak` instead of `code`:

```js
const usersData = {usersList:[{user:"user1",langSpeak:["IND","SPN"]},{user:"user2",langSpeak:["IND"]},{user:"user1",langSpeak:["IND","SPN","JPN"]},{user:"user3",langSpeak:["IND","SPN"]},{user:"user3"}]};

let usersKey = ["user","langSpeak"];
let langValues = ["IND","SPN","JPN"];
let userValues = ["user1"];

let userColl = usersData.usersList.filter(userObj => {
return usersKey.every( usersKey => {
    if(Array.isArray(userObj[usersKey])){
      return langValues.every(x => {
          return userObj[usersKey].includes(x)
      });
    }
    else{
      return userValues.every(user => user === userObj[usersKey]);
    } 
 });
});

console.log(userColl);
```

Comment: Thansk Amardeep. 

But when I Put 
let usersKey = ["user","langSpeak"];
let usersValue = ["user1","IND","SPN","JPN"]

Then it should come only 3rd userList object ,But here I am getting first and third.
Could you please let me know this also.
Thanks very much

Comment: @Sammy please check now

Comment: Is it not possible without using extra let userValues = ?

Comment: @Sammy it is possible but it would be ugly, better to separate out the criteria into two different arrays.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `filter` to filter the array. Use `every` to check if all elements is including a certain string.

```js
const usersData = {"usersList":[{"user":"user1","langSpeak":["IND","SPN"]},{"user":"user2","langSpeak":["IND"]},{"user":"user1","langSpeak":["IND","SPN","JPN"]},{"user":"user3","langSpeak":["IND","SPN"]},{"user":"user3"}]}

let userFilter = "user1";                 //Assign a variable for filtering user
let langFilter = ["IND", "SPN"];          //Assign a variable for filtering language

let result = usersData.usersList.filter(o => o.user == userFilter && o.langSpeak && langFilter.every(e => o.langSpeak.includes(e)));

let finalResult = {                       //Contruct the final object
  usersList: result
}


console.log(finalResult);
```

---

If you really have to use **usersKey** and **usersValue**, you can use a `reduce` to summarize the filter, like:

```js
const usersData = {"usersList":[{"user":"user1","langSpeak":["IND","SPN"]},{"user":"user2","langSpeak":["IND"]},{"user":"user1","langSpeak":["IND","SPN","JPN"]},{"user":"user3","langSpeak":["IND","SPN"]},{"user":"user3"}]}

let usersKey = ["user", "langSpeak"];
let usersValue = ["user1", "IND", "SPN"];

let filter = usersKey.reduce((c, v, i, a) => {
  c[v] = i + 1 === a.length ? usersValue.slice(i) : [usersValue[i]];
  return c;
}, {});


let result = usersData.usersList.filter(o => Object.entries(filter).every(([k, v]) => v.every(x => o[k].includes(x))));

let finalResult = {
  usersList: result
}

console.log(finalResult);
```

Answer (score 1):

`forEach` doesn't return anything - change your code slightly to use `every` and `some`. I also modified it slightly with ternaries:

```js
const usersData = {
  usersList: [{
      user: "user1",
      langSpeak: ["IND", "SPN"],
    },
    {

      user: "user2",
      langSpeak: ["IND"],
    },
    {

      user: "user1",
      langSpeak: ["IND", "SPN", "JPN"],
    },
    {

      user: "user3",
      langSpeak: ["IND", "SPN"],
    },
    {
      user: "user3"
    }
  ]
};

let usersKey = ["user", "langSpeak"];
let usersValue = ["user1", "IND", "SPN"];

let userColl = usersData.usersList.filter(userObj => usersKey.every(k => Array.isArray(userObj[k]) ? usersValue.some(v => userObj[k].includes(v)) : usersValue.includes(userObj[k])));

console.log(userColl);
```

Comment: Thansk Jack. But when I Put let usersKey = ["user","langSpeak"]; let usersValue = ["user1","IND","SPN","JPN"] Then it should come only 3rd userList object ,But here I am getting first and third. Could you please let me know this also. Thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

You can consider changing the variables you are using as filter parameters to an `object`, or maybe a [Map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map).

Note that your approach with variables can present issues in some cases, for example, what would happen if some user is named `IND`. How will you know if some element of the array `usersValue` is related to filtering the property `user` or the property `langSpeak`?

If you use an object, then you can proceed like this:

```js
const usersData = {
  usersList: [
    {user: "user1", langSpeak: ["IND","SPN"]},
    {user: "user2", langSpeak: ["IND"]},
    {user: "user1", langSpeak: ["IND", "SPN", "JPN"]},
    {user: "user3", langSpeak: ["IND", "SPN"]},
    {user: "user3"}
  ]
};

let filterObj = {
  "user": ["user1"],
  "langSpeak": ["IND", "SPN"]
};

let userColl = usersData.usersList.filter(userObj =>
{
    return Object.entries(filterObj).every(([k, v]) =>
    {
        let uVal = userObj[k];

        if (Array.isArray(uVal))
            return v.every(x => uVal.includes(x));
        else
            return v.includes(uVal);
    });
});

console.log(userColl);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could normalize your constraints and take an array, bcause it's easy iterable with another array of a key value and the needed values in other arrays.

Then iterate `constraints` and check if the value from the object is an array or not. Depending on this check iterate the values or take a single check.

```js
var usersList = [{ user: "user1", langSpeak: ["IND", "SPN"] }, { user: "user2", langSpeak: ["IND"] }, { user: "user1", langSpeak: ["IND", "SPN", "JPN"] }, { user: "user3", langSpeak: ["IND", "SPN"] }, { user: "user3" }],
    constraints = [
        ["user", "user1"],
        ["langSpeak", "IND", "SPN"]
    ],
    result = usersList.filter(o => constraints.every(([key, ...values]) => Array.isArray(o[key])
        ? values.every(v => o[key].includes(v))
        : values.includes(o[key])    
    ));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```